# JPA next ID value

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa

I have Postgres DB. I did Entities from it (as *.java classes) and now, I want to create a new Object and commit it to the DB. I hope, the ID will be created automatically by the DB. So I only fill variables like name, address and so on and I don't fill idCustomer. The problem is, when there are records in the DB (created by another app, or simply by SQL INSERT command) and then I run my program, it fails with exception telling me: something.... id=1 is already used. When I run it again (and in the DB there are at least 2 records) if fails again saing id=2 is used...and so on until I run my program for the Nth-time and it passes

```
CREATE TABLE "customer" (
"id_customer" SERIAL NOT NULL,
"surename" char(64) NOT NULL,
"name" char(64) NOT NULL,
"dateofbirth" date NOT NULL,
"gender" char(1) NOT NULL CHECK(gender='m' OR gender='z')
"email" varchar(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
PRIMARY KEY("id_customer")
);
```

How I define ID in Java

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator( name = "customerSeq", sequenceName = "customer_id_customer_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "customerSeq" )
@Column(name = "id_customer")
Long idCustomer;
```

I create new Object (don't fill id) and commit it to DB

```
entitymanager.getTransaction().begin();
entitymanager.persist(createdObject);
entitymanager.getTransaction().commit();
```

My question is: how to get right ID and push it to DB

OR (and better)

how to push to DB created Object without id and the DB should fill it

Comment: How is your database table defined?

Comment: I just edited text and added it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am stupid.

I used SQL INSERT command to put some sample data to the DB before I ran my java program. And I set ID by myself. So the sequence could not increment. Hope you will not spend so many time on this problem.